# is it possible to inject router in a parent class in a way that the child classes dont have to pass the router in the constructor?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a  **service.ts** with dependecies Http, Router and is being injected into a  **parent.ts**.

**child.ts** needs to extend parent classs but should not be bothered about passing service in the constructor. To achieve that, I tried *method (a)* to implemented parent class instead of trusted *method (b)* and adding service to providers in app.module.ts with @NgModule decorator.

**Issue**: I am unable to create injector using *method (a)*

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  constructor(private http: Http,
    private router:Router
    ) {}
}
```

**parent.ts**

*method(a)*

```
export class Parent {
serv:Service
constructor(private name: string) {
const injector = Injector.create({
       providers:
           [{provide: Service, deps: [Http,Router]}, {provide:Http, deps:[]}, {provide: 
Router, deps:[]}]
         })
this.serv = injector.get(Service)
}
}
```

*method (b)*

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    export class BasetaskComponent {
    constructor(private name: string, private router : Router) {}
}
```

**child.ts**

```
export class Child extends Parent {
constructor() {
super('name')
}
```